# How do I export a Facebook list to csv?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

**I want to export a "Facebook list" to a CSV/Excel. I want the name of the page, the number of likes and a URL to the page.**

However, I'll take any amount of information that can be exported out.

This is the list I want exported: https://www.facebook.com/lists/542846765747

**Anyone got any ideas?**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be about _using_ Facebook, not programming.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can use graph api to export any data you want (visible to you). https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api